# proof of a solution to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an equation:

$$
 \dfrac {dy}{dx} = \frac {y(bx-k)}{x(r-ay)}
$$

which I am trying to solve. I know that using separation of variables I should get:

$$
K=\frac { y^rx^k}{e^{ay+bx}}
$$

where K is an arbitrary constant, but I am having trouble getting from the first to the second. I have tried separating variables for which I get:

$$x(r-ay)dy = y(bx-k)dx$$

but when integrating from here I get lost.

Comment: Fixed equations. From the latter one you get
$$
  \left(b-\frac kx\right)\mathrm dx = \left(r-\frac ay\right)\mathrm dy
$$
which is pretty easy to integrate.

Comment: Integrating that just gives me

$$bx-klog(x)=ry-alog(y)$$

and raising both as a power to e I get

$$e^{bx-kx}=e^{ry-ay}$$

Comment: How did you exponentiated $k\log x$?

Comment: I will continue to try to figure that out

Comment: so exponentiating $k log x$ should be $x^k$

Comment: indeed, so now you see the result?

Comment: sort of...after simplifying I am getting

$$K=\frac{y^ax^{-k}}{e^{bx-ry}}$$

I am sure there is a switched up sign somewhere

Comment: My mistake: there shall be $\frac ry-a$ rather than $r-\frac ay$

Comment: perfect! Got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of this question having an answer: your last line can be rewritten as
$$
  \left(b-\frac kx\right)\mathrm dx = \left(\frac ry  -a\right)\mathrm dy
$$
which is easy to integrate. The result will follow immediately after the integration.